# Translate using CakePHP + TwigView + i18n

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, twig

How do I use translate block in my `.tpl` file so that cakephp's extract command would understand it?

I want to translate my CakePHP web application. I am using the [TwigView plugin](https://github.com/predominant/TwigView). TwigView has i18n extract command to generate POT files. My question is why it won't scan my `.tpl` (Twig File) which has a `{% trans %} Hello {% endtrans %}` block.

You can see the Translation functionality in the Readme file of [TwigView](https://github.com/predominant/TwigView).

Comment: Yes, Cake requires using something like <h2><?php echo __('Posts'); ?></h2>. But since I used Twig. I cant use php tag in my View files. I have to use trans block.

Comment: @AD7six - Can you please list the steps in brief on how to use Cake Translation? Or if you know any documentation please link me to the same.

Comment: By the way, can you be more brief in regards to "cake's own translation functions".  Its i18n right? I am using the same.

Comment: I don't use twig (so I'm not the right person to provide an answer), but I'd expect a cakephp-twig plugin to provide a means of extracting the translations. `This is link to TwigView plugin` - it's not a link. Skimming a couple of cakephp-twig plugins they look to expect the use of twig/symfony for generating pot files, cake's extration task is [`Console/cake i18n`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html).

Comment: I updated the question with the link. And I am using  Console/cake i18n to generate POT. But its not scanning by .tpl file.

Comment: k `TwigView has i18n extract command to generate POT files` - where's that? Cake's extract task [does look for tpl files](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ExtractTask.php#L757) but it's not going to match twig-syntax, it only [looks for cake's expected usage](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ExtractTask.php#L368).

Comment: Okay. So to make it simple can you tell me how should I use translate block in .tpl file so that cake's extract function would read it?

Comment: `I don't use twig (so I'm not the right person to provide an answer)` <- I dont know. Afaik it's not possible without using a modified extract task.

Comment: No probs. Will wait for answer. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with cakePHP, but as far as generating POT files goes, cakePHP doesn't need to scan the .tpl files.

The Twig engine has a compiler which basically "converts" each twig view to a PHP script, which is held in the Twig cache folder. At least, that should happen if it's properly configured. These cache files will contain the regular gettext functions which can be recognized.

You must make sure that each view is properly compiled before scanning the cache. This script will allow you to generate the twig cache for all views. After that, you can scan the resulting PHP files.
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html#extracting-template-strings

I'm not sure why you're using cakePHP to generate POT files, but POEDIT (which in turn uses the command line tool xgettext) will definately work this way.